# Cannot access current Test Name in TestComplete

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

We have the method below which is trying to log the name of the test currently being executed

```
function Test()
 {

  var TestItems;

  TestItems = Project.TestItems;
  Log.Message("The " + TestItems.Current.Name + " test item is currently running.");
}
```

This is being run in TestSetup

This is just resulting in a very unhelpful JScript error

> Object required

Stepping through, it appears as though Project.TestItems is assigned, but not Current

Has anyone ever had this problem?

We are using TestComplete using JScript as the scripting language

Project.TestItems is the object that Test Complete says to use to get information about the Project being run.  As I mention above, there is information about the Project and Project.TestItems but TestItems.Current is null

Its as if I am calling this too early but I cant see where else to call it.  It is being called in TestSetup

Paul

Comment: I'm guessing it's jScript from your question. Is this JUnit? This question is very, very unclear

Comment: What is Project.TestItems?

Comment: I will add more clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `Project.TestItems.Current.ElementToBeRun.Caption` instead of `Project.TestItems.Current.Name`.
But you should run this scipt from Project TestItem page.

Comment: Thanks - the key to this was running from the Project TestItem page!